Aligning equations in a system

I am trying to figure out how to properly align the equations present in the various systems. For instance

To get the previous (unsatisfactory) result, I used this code
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* + b^* = 1\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
(1 - b^*)^* - b^* = 1
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
(1 - b^*) - b^* = 1
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
- 2b^* = 0
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
b^* = 0
\end{matrix}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{matrix}
w^* = 1\\
b^* = 0
\end{matrix}\right. \\
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}


It is not clear how you want it to look, but also, it is a bit odd to use matrices here, since what you work with is not matrices.

Please provide more information about how the equations should be aligned. E.g., should the all be left-aligned? Or should they maybe be aligned on the = symbols?

I had among my files one called spear.tex and I guess I used it for answering a question of yours.
And, lo, the file contained code for a system environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{system}{}{%
  \left\{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{}}
}{\endarray\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \begin{system}
w^* + b^* = 1\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
(1 - b^*)^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
(1 - b^*) - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
- 2b^* = 0
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
b^* = 0
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1\\
b^* = 0
\end{system} \\
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& \begin{system}
w^* + b^* = 1\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} &\qquad
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
(1 - b^*)^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} &
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
w^* - b^* = 1
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
(1 - b^*) - b^* = 1
\end{system} &
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
- 2b^* = 0
\end{system} \\
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1 - b^*\\
b^* = 0
\end{system} &
& \begin{system}
w^* = 1\\
b^* = 0
\end{system} \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

Centering equations one above the other is out of question, and so is aligning at the = sign that would produce weird things to read. I also provide a space saving version.

The question was problem to align matrix system and system was in the accepted answer…
